# Convert a string into a valid data range

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to dynamically create a date range in a query function in Google Sheets. It works fine when I enter the range directly, but when I enter it as a string formed from concatenate it doesn't work.

How can I convert the concatenated value into a valid data range. The formula I have is below:

```
=query(CONCATENATE(S$1,"!A:BK"), CONCATENATE("SELECT I, AG, Y, Z WHERE C = '",$A4, "'"),0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing a range reference is not the same as passing a string that looks like a range reference.
If you are building your range like this you want to convert the range reference like string into an actual range reference using `INDIRECT()` like this:
`=query(indirect(S$1&"!A:BK"), CONCATENATE("SELECT I, AG, Y, Z WHERE C = '",$A4, "'"),0)`
Note that I removed the concatenate and replaced it with an ampersand. This is not necessary, its just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively:

```
=query(indirect(S$1&"!A:BK"), "SELECT I, AG, Y, Z WHERE C = '"&$A4& "'",0)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I assume this would work on all string concatenation operations of an indefinite amount of concatenations?